# Handling write and read at the same time in java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a thread which will be continuously logging into a file. I have a function `getLines()` which when called will return last 100 lines of the log file.

My question is whether implementing a  simple BufferedReader inside `getLines()` is enough ? I'm mainly concerned whether reading is valid when a write is going on. I don't mind missing a few lines of code which was written during the process of read though.

Thanks

Comment: You might get some concurrency issues. Does reading and writing really have to happen at the same time? You could lock the file while reading/writing and let only one action be executed at a given time. Another option is to implement a buffer that contains the actions that will be executed in the inserted order.

Comment: Do you use any logging framework? Logging frameworks can help you in achieving you use case.

Comment: No frameworks are used.

Comment: *Why* do you have a method that returns the last 100 lines written to the log? Applications that read their own log files, or those of other applications, have IMHO something seriously wrong with them. Maybe something should be being put to a *database?*

Answer (score 0):

Since Java FileOutputStream / FileInputStream open files in shared mode reading will not interfere with writing. Though in my view it would be better and more efficient to implement a logger that holds last 100 written lines and returns them on demand.